# SQL join with 3 4 tables creating multiple primary key columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, primary-key

I am trying to join 4 tables together, each with a column named `Common Column`, and another column containing numbers. Thus, when joined a table with 5 columns should be created, one `Common Column` column, and one columns from each of the 4 tables. However, the `Common Column` is being created with each join, so it shows up three times in the resulting dataset.

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Table 1`
INNER JOIN `Table 2`
ON `Table 1`.`Common Column` = `Table 2`.`Common Column` 
INNER JOIN `Table 3`
ON `Table 3`.`Common Column` = `Table 2`.`Common Column` 
INNER JOIN `Table 4`
ON `Table 4`.`Common Column` = `Table 3`.`Common Column`;
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6MP6.png)

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJD6.png)

EDIT:

When I use

```
SELECT `Common Column`, num1, num2, num3, num4
```

as my first line, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1052. Column `Common Column` in field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: Pro Tip: Never use `SELECT *`   Explicitly list all the columns you want to select and include the table aliases when you do so.

Comment: Added edit for output that this was giving me

Comment: More edits made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join using the USING syntax, the common column will only appear once:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Table 1`
INNER JOIN `Table 2` USING (`Common Column`)
INNER JOIN `Table 3` USING (`Common Column`)
INNER JOIN `Table 4` USING (`Common Column`);
```

That said, do avoid using `select *`; it is always better to explicitly list the columns you want (qualifying them with table if needed).  If you do

```
SELECT `Table 1`.`Common Column`, num1, num2, num3, num4
```

then it doesn't matter how you join.